# Combine two pieces of JQUERY

Tags: jquery

I' using:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $('#pollform').ajaxForm(function() { 
    $('#pollform').reset();
    }); 
});
```

How can I bring in the following to the above function?

```
$('#myForm2').ajaxForm( { beforeSubmit: validate } );
```

Comment: Is there a problem adding it to a new line inside the function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function you pass in to `$(document).ready()` is a normal function, so you can make multiple calls there:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 

    $('#pollform').ajaxForm(function() { 
        $('#pollform').reset();
      }); 

    $('#myForm2').ajaxForm( { beforeSubmit: validate } ); 
});
```